# why when using inline code in external file doesn't work, but when using function work

Tags: javascript

I know the title of question maybe not be understood, but I will explain that.

Everyone know we can use any of the following way.

Example(1)

```
document.getElementById('idofelement').onsubmit = function() {
   alert('Go ahead');
   return false;
}
```

Example(2)

```
function DisplayMsg(){
   alert('Go ahead');
   return false;
}

// and in HTML
<form action="file.php" method="post" onsubmit="return DisplayMsg();">
```

**My question (1):**
What is the difference between the two ways or two examples

**My question (2) :**
Why the `example (1)` not work in external JavaScript file, but work with me when it is inserted near by the target HTML code.
While the `example (2)` work in any place Whether in external file or near by the target HTML code.

Comment: on which event you execute example (1) ?

Comment: Try adding an `onLoad` wrapper for example 1 (or `ready` wrapper, if you were using jQuery)

Comment: Thanks everyone,   are there other opinions?

Answer (score 0):

You should always call the method getElementById after the document is loaded. So as suggested by @JanDvorak you should wrap that by `$.ready()` using jQuery. And if you are not, use `window.onload = function()` instead.

btw: don't forget semicolon after definition of function, IE is vulnerable to this syntax

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but, is possible answer to my question (1) if you know.

Comment: I think There is no difference between them except when they are excuted, the first one in your example will be excuted right away, and at that point the HTML document MAY NOT be completely parsed by your browser, so you can't get a dom object identified by its ID( it doesn't yet exist), neither can you bind the event handler to it. The second one will be excuted after the browser parsed the form element, so it can bind the event handler function correctly to the element form.